# What can I do about losing reference to a progress bar which is in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have three fragments, Play, Dropbox and Settings inside a tab host.

Inside the Dropbox fragment, I have a class variable, 'progressBar'. I allocate it in the onActivityCreated.

```
   if(progressBar == null) 
    {
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
    }
```

I update it with this:

```
DropboxAPI.DropboxFileInfo info = mDBApi.getFile(directoryOfFile, null, outputStream, new ProgressListener() {
     @Override
     public long progressInterval() { return 2000; }
     public void onProgress(long downloadedSoFar, long totalSize) {
                      final double dProgress = ((double)downloadedSoFar / totalSize)*100.0;
                      getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() {
                              System.out.println(dProgress);
                              progressBar.setProgress((int) dProgress);

                          }
                      });
                  }
```

This works perfectly, however, when I move to another fragment and come back it stays stuck on where it was left. It's annoying because I can still see my  `System.out.println(dProgress)` working.  Nothing I seem to do allows me to reallocate the progress bar and it work. Is there any way I can do this? Anyone just point me in the right direction as to how this achieved? I had a look at a few apps as to how they do it ( I'm an iOS guy ) and they all just prompted the user with a progress screen open, but I want users to be able to do something while downloading.

p.s I've tried this without the null condition.

Comment: I'm only guessing here, but perhaps it'll help if you re-assign `progressBar` with `findById()` before updating it with `setProgress()`. I suppose switching fragments causes them to be re-created, so you'll have to look up widgets again. The same 'freezing progressbar' probably happens when you rotate the device (which also gets things re-created).

Comment: I'll give it a whirl now but think I tried this already, thanks

Comment: Hi man, thanks for this. It put my brain on the right track. I actually had a final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal); sitting above this O_O so embarassing.. in iOS it would have told me that this variable will override the class one with a nice big yellow warning. It didn't with this!!!! thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Replace this ..

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          System.out.println(dProgress);
                          progressBar.setProgress((int) dProgress);

                      }
                  });
```

with this..

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           System.out.println(dProgress);
                          progressBar.setProgress((int) dProgress);
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```